# How to extract a tar.gz file from a remote link using python

Tags: python-requests, gzip, tar

I am trying to download an http.tar.gz link and extract it through python 2.7 using requests. I cannot seem to find a code that will allow the link to be downloaded and extract the entire tar.gz folder into my documents. If anyone has any suggestions, please help! I need this done for work and my boss does not understand my question...

Comment: Please add the sample code which you tried but not working so others can help you correcting it.

Answer (score 0):

The library you're looking for is [tarfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html). Use *tarfile.*`extractall()`.

Comment: Provide context for links, and provide __working__ code to answer the question rather than a method that doesn't provide anything related tot he question which asked about remote files

Comment: @Stof The question already identified the library they want to use for downloading, which is [`requests`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). Upon downloading, `tarfile` will extract the contents. Also stackoverflow is not a code-writing service. If they put some code in their question with what they had tried, then I might have provided some suggested changes to allow them to move forward. With `requests` and `tarfile` they should be able to at least try to write code to solve their problem.